# How to run one command if a previous command succeeds, otherwise run another command

Tags: bash

I am trying to check if a process (assume it is called `some_process`) is running on a server. If it is, then echo 1, otherwise echo 0.

This is the command that I am using but it only works partially (more info below). Note that I need to write the script in one line.

```
ps aux | grep some_proces[s] > /tmp/test.txt && if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

**Note:** The `[s]` in `some_proces[s]` is to prevent `grep` from returning itself.

If `some_process` is running, then `"1"` gets echoed, which is fine. However, if `some_process` is not running, nothing gets echoed.

Comment: You can use `ps -Ccmd` to find processes whose command name is "cmd", which can completely eliminate the `grep`. `ps` will set the exit code to some non-zero value if it fails to find a matching process.

Comment: Thanks to @rici I solved with easy `ps -C php && echo 1 || php d.php` this means if a php is running print an echo if not execute that

Answer (score 418, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly check `$?`.  Just do:

```
ps aux | grep some_proces[s] > /tmp/test.txt && echo 1 || echo 0
```

Note that this relies on echo not failing, which is certainly not guaranteed.  A more reliable way to write this is:

```
if ps aux | grep some_proces[s] > /tmp/test.txt; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

Comment: If `echo 1` fail, then `echo 0` will be executed. In this case, echo 1 will never fail, but Note that A && B || C is not if-then-else. C may run when A is true.(from [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck)).

Comment: @schemacs makes a very valid point: editing to provide a much better alternative.

Comment: Is it necessary to re-direct the output of the ps command to a file ? Would this not work ? `if ps aux | grep some_proces[s]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi`.  Locally it seems to work for me. Is it because OP had the redirection in the command he tried?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to redirect the output.  I merely ape the original position, since I assume the output is being saved for a reason.  Often this sort of thing is merely suppressed (with `grep -q` or redirected to /dev/null).

Comment: I would use `pgrep`.

Comment: The && and || to construct a ternary operator is a good touch

Comment: The redirection will happen before the command executes, but the return code will be the status of the command.  If the redirection fails, the command will not execute and the return status is non-zero.

Comment: `if then else` in one line is also ok for me.

Answer (score 92):

`&&` means "and if successful"; by placing your `if` statement on the right-hand side of it, you ensure that it will only run if `grep` returns `0`. To fix it, use `;` instead:

> `ps aux | grep some_proces[s] > /tmp/test.txt ; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi`

(or just use a line-break).

Comment: +1 This is a much better answer, as it actually answers the question as opposed to merely providing an alternative.

Comment: This assumes we know `$?`.  I believe that's the most recent return code?  But isn't this whole exercise basically creating a return code?  How about `ps aux | grep some_proces[s] > /tmp/test.txt ; echo $?` ?

Comment: @Jeter-work: Doesn't that give the opposite of the desired result? (Though I suppose you could fix that by prefixing the first command with `!`.)

Comment: I tested it and the redirect only runs if there's output from the grep statement.  `pgrep -q some_process > /tmp/test.txt; echo $?` will be 0 if the process is running.  1 if not.  And you're right, it is actually inverted.

Comment: @ruakh Yes, success will return 0, which is the recommendation for return code for 'success'.

Answer (score 67):

Use `grep -vc` to ignore `grep` in the `ps` output and count the lines simultaneously.

```
if [[ $(ps aux | grep process | grep -vc grep)  > 0 ]] ; then echo 1; else echo 0 ; fi
```

Answer (score 19):

You can make full use of the `&&` and `||` operators like this:

```
ps aux | grep some_proces[s] > /tmp/test.txt && echo 1 || echo 0
```

For excluding grep itself, you could also do something like:

```
ps aux | grep some_proces | grep -vw grep > /tmp/test.txt && echo 1 || echo 0
```

Answer (score 11):

```
pgrep -q some_process && echo 1 || echo 0
```

more oneliners [here](https://github.com/onceupon/Bash-Oneliner)

Comment: `pgrep -q some_process > /tmp/test.txt && echo 1 || echo 0` or `pgrep -q some_process > /tmp/test.txt; echo $?;`  I'm assuming there's a reason to keep the grep output.  And suggesting using the return code to skip using the ternary.  Less operations.

Answer (score 0):

checkdb:
image: mysql:8.0.31
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}

```
entrypoint: sh -c  'while true; do 
                mysql -h ${DB_MYSQL:-db} --user=${MYSQL_USER:-root} --password=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} --execute "use ${MYSQL_DATABASE};";
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then exit 0; fi; 
                sleep 5;
              done'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).