# Bash: How to catch git command failure?

Tags: git, bash

I have a command:

```
...
{
    git filter-branch -f --env-filter "$ENVFILTER" >/dev/null
    echo "Git updated. Run 'git push -f BRANCH_NAME' to push your changes."
} || {
    echo "Git failed. Please make sure you run this on a clean working directory." // this doesn't ever get called
}
```

The happy path works, but it doesn't look like the `||` ever gets executed. This is what a failure looks like:

```
[~/Documents/my-repo]$ my-custom-command                                                                           
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
Git updated. Run 'git push -f BRANCH_NAME' to push your changes.
[
```

Is there a way to catch that error? I wouldn't mind even if it was just matching the `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged` string that gets printed out (which I would like to hide by the way)

Comment: the `echo "Git updated"` line kills your error code. It just sets it to 0.

Comment: @yellowantphil if there's any possibility of the `echo` failing, that is dicey - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17203203/2877364) (which I found very informative when I stumbled across it).

Comment: @cxw did not think of that. I thought yellowantphil syntax was very good. But ksh forever :) But seriously, why should `echo` fail with a fixed string argument?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't know :) :) .  It just jumped out at me because after I read the linked answer I stopped using `x && y || z` even though that is the most natural syntax.  I guess I am trying to help folks avoid (admittedly unlikely) pitfalls in hopes they will do the same for me. ;)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ooh!  How about this?  `echo "foo" 1>&-` gives `-bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor` and `$?=1`.  If you had an overly complex script that played games with stdout, it could actually happen. :)

Comment: that must be the only case ! but you're right. Could be a funny question to ask: how to make echo fail?

Comment: @yellowantphil save your answer for the upcomping question :) very good in the meanwhile ! although the user would become crazy _before_ noticing the error code is wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the `echo` command after your `git` will be executed no matter what, that's the first problem.
The second problem is that this `echo` command updates the error code: first error code is overwritten.

I would suggest a "classical" approach (maybe a bit old-fashioned, I was raised with ksh):

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "$ENVFILTER" >/dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
    echo "Git updated. Run 'git push -f BRANCH_NAME' to push your changes."
else
    echo "Git failed. Please make sure you run this on a clean working directory."
fi
```

slightly off-topic: MS-DOS/Windows users will be surprised by that, since in Windows, `echo` does not change `ERRORLEVEL`

Comment: @Edmund you can also inline: `if git filter-branch -f --env-filter "$ENVFILTER" >/dev/null ; then` and everything else the same, if you want something shorter.

Comment: Hah, calling `ksh` "old fashioned"... the Korn shell  only dates back to 1983! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell (Admittedly I only started a few years before that myself...)

Comment: In 1983 I was 12, just learning BASIC and I'm a retrogaming/retrocomputing fan, so it was not a deprecative comment :)