# How to read output of command while still hiding it?

Tags: bash, git, error-handling

I have a custom Git command which conditionally deletes local branches that have a gone remote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

GONE_BRANCHES=$(git branch -vv | grep 'origin/.*: gone]' | awk '{print $1}')

if [ -z "$GONE_BRANCHES" ]; then
  echo "Could not find any local branches that have a gone remote"
  exit 0
fi

if [ "$1" = "-f" ]; then
  echo "$GONE_BRANCHES" | xargs git branch -D
else
  echo "$GONE_BRANCHES" | xargs git branch -d 2>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    FAILED_TO_DELETE="true"
  fi
fi

if [ "$FAILED_TO_DELETE" = "true" ]; then
  echo "error: Some local branches are not fully merged."
  echo "If you are sure you want to delete them, run 'git-glean -f'"
fi
```

Based off the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094531/bash-how-to-catch-git-command-failure) I am trying to build a solution which still outputs the result of the `git branch -d`, but if it fails to remove one, swallow (hide) the error message and echo a custom error message instead.

The problem is that the conditional error message never triggers (for those branches that could not be deleted with `git branch -d`).

Comment: It seems like it's what you're currently doing. What's not working?

Comment: Updated question to clarify, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `xargs` manpage, it states :

> EXIT STATUS
>     xargs exits with the following status:
>     0 if it succeeds
>     123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125

Xargs will not exit with the `1"` status if the process exited with the 1 status. Change your condition to:

```
 echo "$GONE_BRANCHES" | xargs git branch -d 2>/dev/null
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```

Comment: Thank you! Will mark as accepted once I figure out this weird behaviour... the command, for whatever reason, seems to at first notice there are not fully merged branches (and outputs the error msg) and then deletes the branch anyway :confused: -- that is, the output is `Some local branches are not fully merged...` followed by `Deleted branch $branchName (was $commitHash)`

Comment: Thanks! The problem was exactly that - checking for the wrong error code. Good example of why checking for a non-zero code is (most of the time) better practise, when non-zero always means the command has failed!